# can the SelectionIndicator for a UIPickerView be customized?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uipickerview

I need to have a UIPickerView as UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer but with more than 2 columns, like hours, minutes, seconds. So doing a UIPickerView like this is a no brainer, but I'd like to show the words 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds' and so on, but on the selectionIndicator. Is there a way to customize this?

-Carlos

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was to add a UILabel with a clearColor as background and put it over the picker, at the exact position where the selectionIndicator shows.